# Why isnt my border containing the Button?

Tags: html, css, surround

I want the "Dive" button to be surrounded by the border aswell. Anybody got an Idea?
[`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/2dxu4t5g/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You played a little too much with `position:relative`. You can solve your problem by adding a `padding-bottom:40px` for class `logboxcontain`, but I would recommend trying using less relative positioning.